# Puting 'is' after plural subject

Tags: plural-forms, subjects

Given sentence 'Dogs are my choice', can I use singular verb form for any reason?

Comment: Yes, if *Dogs* was a proper noun

Comment: Seems like 'dogs' is not proper noun in example provided.

Comment: if that so, *dogs is..* is ungrammatical

Comment: Why would you even ask this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "justify" the singular verb form *Dogs **is** my choice* on the grounds that *my **choice*** is singular, or by appeal to the [**use–mention** distinction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use%E2%80%93mention_distinction) (the reference is to ***dogs*** as a single token, not to the plurality of animals represented *by* that token).

It's not really any different than *Fish and chips **was** my choice in the restaurant* or *When it comes to sexual preference, my choice **is** women*. As a general *tendency*, BrE is more flexible in this area than AmE, in that we're more likely to ignore strict logic/grammar, to reflect the *semantics* of an utterance.

---

I don't have any problem with...

> Speaker A: [*If your choice **is** cats and dogs, then choose cats and dogs, but don't run around and wonder what the rabbits are doing.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22choice%20is%20cats%22)
>
> ...after which the following conversation could ensue...
>
> Speaker B: *You said "cats **and** dogs", but I only like dogs, not cats. What should I say my choice is?*
>    Speaker A: *Just say "**My choice is dogs**". Only a misguided pedant would argue with that!*
>    Speaker B: *Okay, but can I reorder that to "**Dogs is my choice**" if I want?*
>    Speaker A: *Sure. But even some people who aren't particularly pedantic might not like it much*

Comment: I agree with the general thrust of your answer, but "my choice is women" is not really the same thing at all, because *my choice* is the subject of the clause, and is undeniably singular, unlike *women* or *dogs*.  Personally, I think "my choice is dogs" sounds clashingly wrong, unless we're using that use-mention distinction and, for example, "dogs" was just the label of something.  For example, if Alex Trebek says to you, "The categories are ____, ____, and 'dogs'), you could say "My choice is 'dogs'", but it should really be punctuated that way to indicate the distinction.

Comment: @stangdon: You're simply confirming the truth of my last line above. No-one is likely to complain about *My choice is [plural X]*, but you're one of those people who objects on ***syntactic / logical*** grounds to the reversal *[Plural X] is my choice*. Me, I consider each example on on its merits, taking ***semantics*** into account. Sometimes it's more contextually relevant that there's only one choice; sometimes it's more relevant that the things chosen are a plurality (albeit chosen "collectively").

Answer (score 0):

Noodles is my dish.
Pasta is my dish.
Cakes is my dish.
My dish is cakes.
My dish is donuts.
My dish is in baskets.
My dish is in cartons.
I want an excellent dish.
He buy
Cars is my vehicle.
10 dogs is extremely.

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. Your answer would be greatly improved if you would explain the examples you have provided, perhaps with citations from actual usage. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance on writing strong answers.